# c++ overloading operator << of ofstream for Report/Logger class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a report/logger Class in c++.

I want to have in the main an object called Report and apply to this class the operator << to write to file multiple strings just like ofstream does.

So instead of using the following code:

```
  ofstream myfile ("d://example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "This is a line.\n" << "Heya!!!" << endl;
    myfile.close();
  }
```

I would like to have something like the following :

```
  Report rLogger ("d://example.txt"); // Report C'tor (const string& s)
  logger << "This is a line.\n" << "Heya!!!" << endl;
// the destructor of rLogger will close the file when it dies...
```

I just can't find out a way to write the operator << as a member function which seems exactly what I need here. The only way I can use the operator << is as friend which isn't helpful in this case. Can someone give me an idea how can I implement it as above?

Thank in advance,
Guy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class Report {
    public:
        Report() {}

        Report(std::string _str) : stream(_str) {}

        Report& operator <<(std::string str) {
            if (stream.is_open())
                stream << str;

            return *this;
        }

        ~Report() { stream.close(); }

        std::ofstream stream;
};
```

For the above you must also include the `<string>` header.

Comment: I get the following error: 1 IntelliSense: too few parameters for this operator function.

Comment: @Guy I have to make a few more changes, 1 sec

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want to create a stream-like type. Do **not** create a stream like type by overloading the output operator `<<`! The way to create a new stream-like type is to create a stream buffer (i.e., a type derived from `std::streambuf`) and use this to initialize an `std::ostream` object, probably by using `std::ostream` as a base class.

The other approaches for overloading `operator<<()` won't work for manipulators like `std::endl`: the manipulator `std::endl` is a function template and for deducing it template arguments when being used it is necessary to have an overload which can be used to deduce the type correct. The `std::ostream` class does this by providing suitable special overloads.

I realize that this isn't answering your question about how to overload `operator<<()` as a member but I think it is the wrong approach and it will probably yield better results changing the way the problem is addressed. I would provide more detail on how to create the corresponding classes but there isn't sufficient context given.

Comment: I didn't even think about what you were saying but It sounds like the "appropriate solution" - I also noticed that the std::endl didn't work so I used \n instead. Is there any reference you can give me where I can find out how to create a stream buffer for this small purpose ? Thank you for the respond.

Comment: Searching for "dietmar kuehl" and streambuf yields plenty examples, some with others without explanation. Nicolai Josuttis's "The C++ Standard Library" also has a section on stream buffers. You haven't stated what the special behavior of your stream should be, otherwise I could give more specific pointers and/or advice.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your problems stem from needing to insert different types to your report, such as `"Heya!!!"` or `std::endl`.

One flexible solution is to **do this with templates.**

You may implement it as a member function, where the `Report` is pointed to by `this`:

```
class Report {
    public:

        template < typename T >
        Report& operator <<( const T &data ) { ... }

};
```

Or as a friend function, where there is no `this` and `Report` is instead explicitly mentioned and named:

```
class Report {
    public:

        template < typename T >
        friend Report& operator <<( Report &r, const T &data ) { ... }

};
```

Or as a stand-alone function, if the `Report` has enough public methods to do the job.

```
template < typename T >
Report& operator <<( Report &r, const T &data ) { ... }
```

Comment: Nicely put. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To implement it as a member function and be able to concatenate several streams you just have to return a reference to the object at the end of the function, e.g.:

```
class Report {
public:

    // ...

    Report& operator<<(const char *text) {
        // write text to file...

        return *this;
    }

};
```

Here is a very simple example that prints to standard output instead of a file: http://codepad.org/S8QeJZ1x

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to make sure the file is closed after use, class `Report` is unnecessary.  `std::ofstream`'s destructor already closes its file.

The other answers so far, which try to define a templated `operator<<` have a problem:  They won't work with some manipulators including `std::endl`, since it's actually a function template, and the compiler can't figure out what sort of instantiation it should use.

If the purpose of class `Report` is to add or modify something in the data going through, that's more easily and more correctly done by defining your own streambuf.  [This article](http://gabisoft.free.fr/articles/fltrsbf1.html) by James Kanze describes how to do that.

Comment: Just what I was currently looking for! Thanks!